# Reading a text file with multiple columns?

Tags: python

I am suppose to read a large text file that consists of states, years, quarters and index. However when I run my code it receives an error saying "not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2). Any ideas on where I may be going wrong?

```
def read(filepath):
    data = {}
    fd = open(filepath)
    for line in fd:
        state, year, qtr, index = line.split()
        if len(state) == 2:
            if index != '.':
                if state not in data:
                    data[state] = [QuarterHPI(int(year), int(qtr), float(index))]
    print(data)
    return data
```

Comment: At least one of your lines in your text file doesn't include 4 items - a data quality issue. What are you expected to do with bad data, ignore, default, etc. e.g. wrap `line.split()` in `try: ... except ValueError: continue` to ignore bad lines.

Comment: That error means that you have some line that only has two values on it.

Comment: why don't you show us a sample dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state, year, qtr, index = line.split()`

is waiting for 4 items, but `line.split()` seems returned only 2.